# skimage.io.imshow(winname, image_arr) gives TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

Here is the code:

```
#  https://github.com/anilkay/ComputerVisionExamples/blob/master/beatian.ipynb
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.io as imageio
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import sys

we_photo=cv2.imread(r"data\photos\we_small.jpg")

if we_photo is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")

winname = "Photo to analize"
cv2.namedWindow(winname) 
imageio.imshow(winname, we_photo)
```

I have picked this code from [here](https://github.com/anilkay/ComputerVisionExamples/blob/master/beatian.ipynb).  I only added window for my large photo. This code
gives the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\OneDrive\=Книги=\MachineLearning\ML_code_PyTorch\recognition\dlib68_one_image.py", line 18, in <module>
    imageio.imshow(winname, we_photo)
  File "D:\Games\conda\envs\dlib\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 158, in imshow
    arr = call_plugin('imread', arr, plugin=plugin)
  File "D:\Games\conda\envs\dlib\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 200, in call_plugin
    _load(plugin)
  File "D:\Games\conda\envs\dlib\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 287, in _load
    if plugin in find_available_plugins(loaded=True):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Idk what to think about. The code was run on Windows10/Anaconda in VS Code.
Without window like `imageio.imshow(we_photo)` finished but doesn't show anything.

Comment: For some reason you're trying to use `skimage.io.imshow` as if it was `cv2.imshow` -- it's not, and it has a [different signature](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imshow).

Comment: Thanks. so the source of this code if wrong now. Thanks.
Can You write the answer - I'd mark Your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```py
import cv2


we_photo=cv2.imread(r"data\photos\we_small.jpg")

if we_photo is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")

winname = "Photo to analize"
cv2.imshow(winname, we_photo)
```